# Метки разного цвета,в зависимости от района

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, yandex-maps-api

Добавляю из массива с адресами на карту метки

```
 var addresses = [
        'Санкт-Петербург, Проспект Стачек, 100',
        'Санкт-Петербург, Проспект Славы, 23'
    ];
    /*--------------*/
     ymaps.ready(init);

    function init(){
        var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [59.93, 30.33],
            zoom: 12,
            behaviors: ['default', 'scrollZoom'],
            controls: ['mapTools'],

        });

        function addLabel(map, addr) {
            var geocoder = new ymaps.geocode( addr, { results: 1 } );
            geocoder.then(function (res) {
                map.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects.get(0));                                  
            });
        }

        for (var i=0; i<addresses.length; ++i) {
            addLabel(map, addresses[i]);

        }
    }
```

Нужно в зависимости от района покрасить их в разный цвет. Или хотя бы полигоны на сами районы сделать
Как определить район по адресу?
http://jsfiddle.net/pw4Tc/97/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определить район через API можно только через обратное геокодирование по координатам. При запросе к геокодеру нужно передать координаты точки и опцию `kind` со значением `district`, в этом случае геокодер вернет название района, зная которое можно красить метки в некоторый цвет из заданного набора.

Определить район города в вашем случае можно так:

```
function addLabel(map, addr) {
    ymaps.geocode(addr, { results: 1 })
        .then(function (res) {
            var point = res.geoObjects.get(0);
            var coordinates = point.geometry.getCoordinates();

            ymaps.geocode(coordinates, { kind: 'district' })
                    .then(function (res) {
                        var district = res.geoObjects.get(0)

                        // Название района города
                        district.properties.get('name');

                        // Добавление точки на карту
                        map.geoObjects.add(point);
                    });
        });
}
```

Comment: Он определяет муниципальные округи, а мне районы нужны,Кировский,Калининский и тд)

Comment: @zkolya, да, действительно, но информация о районах там все равно присутствует, можно, например, использовать свойство `description`, `district.properties.get('description')`.

Comment: Не затруднит ли подсказать,что то я залип, как передать это значение и использовать,например в цикле?Вне функции.

Comment: @zkolya, передавайте, например, в функцию addLabel коллбек, а когда название района станет известно, то вызывайте этот коллбек и передавайте в него название района, или используйте Promise.